# Banner Insertion on Proxy Squid

Tags: apache-2.2, php, python, squid, perl

```
hey guys are you aware of anchorfree vpn?, i have used them before, however i am running my cybercafe on squid, and i want to advertise using squid, i would like to know how to add a banner at the top of every page randomly just like anchorfree thank you.
```

Answer (score 1):

here's some tips:

it's called ICAP - Internet Content Adaptation Protocol

1. http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/ICAP#ICAP_Servers
2. greasyspoon.sourceforge.net/
3. c-icap.sourceforge.net/

use beta versions.